# Space complexity of recursive Towers of Hanoi with memoization?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, memoization

What is the space-complexity of recursive Towers of Hanoi with memoization?

**I guess the recursive algorithm has 2^(n-1) recursive calls, so the space-complexity is 2^(n-1)?**

Edit after reading some comments below: I think there is no repetitive recursive calls here so memoization is not helpful at all. If I use memoization, all the recursive calls will be stored and hence raise the space-complexity to the maximum: 2^(n-1). Is it better not to use memoization for this recursive algorithm?

Can you confirm my justification?

Towers of Hanoi problem: list moves to move n disks from "source" peg to "target" peg using "mid" peg.

Recursive algorithm:

```
def hanoi_tower_solution(n, source, mid, target):
    if n == 1:
        disk_move(source, target)
    else:
        hanoi_tower_solution(n-1, source, target, mid)
        disk_move(source, target)
        hanoi_tower_solution(n-1, mid, source, target)
```

Comment: "has 2^(n-1) recursive calls ... so the space-complexity is 2^(n-1)" That's a non sequitur. Not all of the calls are active at the same time.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The omitted part is important though. OP says "memoization isn't helpful **at all**, which can be interpeted as "all states are going to be stored", so regardless of when the calls were invoked - they are all stored.

Comment: The algorithm produces output that is (2^n)-1 long, so any cache for that output is at least that long.

Comment: (I am the OP) I think n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m is right, but i would like more details. Now it seems to me that the memoization here is hurful, so i modified the question to without memoization.

Comment: @ThangTran - to clarify further, I think you're trying to ask whether dp offers benefit of any sort.  One answer is (A) "yes, *but* at a large space cost", another is (B) "no, *and* at a large space cost".  I think your hunch is B, and I think you're right. I'm more confident in my ability to code than to theorize, so the way I'd confirm the hunch is to implement and count successful gets from the cache.

Comment: Since memoization is useless for this problem, it's not obvious how you would use it... so I don't think this question has a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess the recursive algorithm has 2<sup>−1</sup> recursive calls, so the space-complexity is 2<sup>−1</sup>?

No. Although there are that many *calls*, there are calls returning before the next recursive call is made, and so the (stack) memory used by the previous call is first freed and then reused again.

What counts is the deepest *depth* of recursion. Since −1 is passed as argument, and with  equal to 1 the deepest point of recursion is reached, the depth is . Therefor the space complexity is O().

> If I use memoization, all the recursive calls will be stored and hence raise the space-complexity to the maximum: 2<sup>−1</sup>.

True.

> Is it better not to use memoization for this recursive algorithm?

That depends on what exactly is memoized. If the simple *state* of the towers is used as key, then it is useless, as no state occurs twice in a solution.

We could imagine a kind of memoization where the order of the towers is not represented in the key, and only the number of sequential, smallest discs on one stack is used as key -- with the idea that this substack must get moved to another location. The moves for moving the 3 smallest discs from tower B to C could then make use of a memoized solution for moving them from tower A to B. You would then take care of how the moves are encoded, so they translate correctly to the actual situation of the towers. This would then require about O() entries for memoization, but each entry would list the moves to be made, which is again exponential in terms of the number of discs to move...

There really is not much gain with memoization, as:

1. Anyhow all the 2<sup>−1</sup> moves must be made, so there is no time gain.
2. There is a straightforward solution that does not require recursion: the number of discs, the current state and move number uniquely define which move must be played. That logic is explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution). And then it runs with constant auxiliary space complexity (so not counting the memory used for representing the current state).